# How to destroy model with values

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm kind of new to rails.  I have a model called follows that has to values (requestor and following). I am having trouble creating a button that destroys a select model with two values[image]

```
<dt>User ID:</dt>
<dd><%= @user.id %></dd>

<dt>User email:</dt>
<dd><%= @user.email %></dd>

<% if Follow.where(:requestor => current_user.id, :following =>@user.id).present? %>    
    <%= button_to 'Unfollow', follow_url, method: :delete, class: "text-danger", data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
<% else %>
    <%= button_to "Follow", {:controller => 'follows', :action => 'create', :requestor => current_user.id, :following => @user.id}, {:method => :post} %>
<% end %>
```

The Follow button below in the else statement works, but I cannot figure out how to get the destroy button to work.  I'm executing these buttons on the User show page instead of on the follow index.[image]

```
def destroy
    @follow.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to follows_url, notice: 'Follow was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_follow
      @follow = Follow.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def follow_params
      params.permit(:requestor, :following)
    end
    def require_permission
      if Follow.find(params[:id]).user != current_user
        redirect_to goals_url, flash: { error: "You do not have permission to do that."}
      end
    end
end
```

I keep getting couldn't find Follow with 'id' error.  It deletes sometimes, but the majority of the time I get this error.[image]

Routes.  uses general format

```
require 'sidekiq/web'

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :follows
  resources :accounts
  resources :goals
  resources :retirements
  get '/users', to: 'users#index'
  get '/user/:id', to: 'users#show', as: 'user'
  resources :calculate_debts
  get '/privacy', to: 'home#privacy'
  get '/terms', to: 'home#terms'
    authenticate :user, lambda { |u| u.admin? } do
      mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq'
    end


  resources :notifications, only: [:index]
  resources :announcements, only: [:index]
  devise_for :users, controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: "users/omniauth_callbacks" }
  root to: 'home#index'
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

Comment: Can you update your question to explain what isn't working specifically?  And please post text in there, not more images.

Comment: Also it would be useful to see your routes.rb

Comment: I added the routes and the code for the above pictures.  Also posted the error I received.

Answer (score 0):

> It deletes sometimes, but the majority of the time I get this error

If it works "sometimes" then my guess would be that you are not re-rendering your page after your delete, and you might end up clicking the "Unfollow" button twice on the same record, which will raise a `RecordNotFound` error like you showed.

Your html redirect seems fine but make sure you are also refreshing the page when the request is in json format.